# Как в кортеже заменить все фамилии на случайные из созданного файла?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, tuple

Нужно в кортеже заменить все фамилии на случайные из созданного файла.

```
import random

foot = [('Андреев', 2001,'Полузащитник', 15, 10, 'Москва'),
('Иванов', 1990, 'Защитник',9, 5, 'Тула'),
('Николаев', 2000, 'Нападающий',10, 5, 'Тюмень'),
('Мамаев', 2002, 'Вратарь',13, 7, 'Ульяновск'),
('Александров', 1997, 'Защитник',10, 4, 'Оренбург')]


x = list(foot)

a = list(open('test.txt'))
a = random.choice(a)#Генерирует случайную фамилию из файла.
x[0][0] = a
print(a)
```

Comment: Кортежи иммутабельны. Только если новые кортежи делать из старых.

Comment: Простое решение - заменить кортежи на строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
a = list(open('test.txt'))
for i in foot:
    name = random.choice(a)
    i[0] = name
print(foot)
```

Comment: Это заменит строку целиком, а не только фамилию.

Comment: @insolor, если перепишу кортеж в строку , то код по такому же принципу писать ?

Comment: @АндрейМалых в вашем коде просто в списке игроков круглые скобки кортежей на квадратные списков (например, `[('Андреев', 2001,'Полузащитник', 15, 10, 'Москва'),` на `[['Андреев', 2001,'Полузащитник', 15, 10, 'Москва'],`), и ошибка уйдет, без проблем можно будет менять фамилию внутри строк, больше ничего в коде не нужно будет менять. Ну единственно я подозреваю что у вас из файла фамилии с переносами строк в конце считаются, но это уже отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то этот вопрос часто повторяется.
Перемешайте и последовательно читайте список, чтобы не было повторений.

Перемешивает изменяемую последовательность случайным образом.

```
import random
random.shuffle(lst)
```

Внимание! изменяет непосредственно сам объект последовательности.

Конечно изменить кортеж в список, изменить значения и если нужно, список в кортеж.

---

Мой ответ оказался не полезным, решил дополнить, потому что считаю что использовать random.choice не разумно, т.к могут быть повторы.

```
import random

foot = [('Андреев', 2001,'Полузащитник', 15, 10, 'Москва'),
('Иванов', 1990, 'Защитник',9, 5, 'Тула'),
('Николаев', 2000, 'Нападающий',10, 5, 'Тюмень'),
('Мамаев', 2002, 'Вратарь',13, 7, 'Ульяновск'),
('Александров', 1997, 'Защитник',10, 4, 'Оренбург')]
file=['Салах','Левандовски','Роналду','Мане','Мбаппе','Неймар']
random.shuffle(file)
foot_out=[]
for el1,el2 in zip(file,foot):
    out=(list(el2[1:]))
    out.insert(0,el1)
    foot_out+=(tuple(out),)
foot=foot_out
print(foot)
```

Замечание, пример учебный по этому нужно следить, чтобы len(foot) и len(file) , были равны.

Comment: Кстати, работать будет и с разной длиной, главное чтобы в файле было больше записей, чем в данных

Comment: Да, с разной длиной работает, останавливается на том, что короче. Думал что будет индекс вне диапазона.